# $.getJSON Callback Help - Not a Function

Tags: javascript, callback, getjson

My context is as follows:

I have a variable 'qq' - I want to assign data to this variable from an API call, and once the data has been assigned, I then use this data in a paint/binding process.

The API call and assigning to var 'qq' works fine - but I cant seem to get my callback to work - I keep getting an error: callback() is not a function

This is what my code currently looks like:

```js
var qq = [];

// binding function - to be run after data loader has completed
function sayIamDone() {
    alert('I Am Done');
    // do data bindings with qq
}

// load data from api into var qq

function dataLoader(inp,callback) {
    let url = 'http://localhost:65232/api/layercolor/' + inp;
    console.log(url);
    $.getJSON(url,function(result) {
        qq = eval('({' + result + '})');    
        //console.log(qq);
        callback();
    });
                
}

// call data loader
dataLoader('Prov', sayIamDone());
```

From the above I get the following error in my chrome console:

*Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function*

I have tried the following - which seems to work:

```html
dataLoader('Prov', function () { alert('I Am Done');});
```

but it is not ideal in my context, as I want to call dataLoader('Prov',XXX()) where XXX() could be a number of different functions using the newly loaded values in qq

Any suggestions as to where I am missing the boat please?

Comment: Did you include jquery before your code above?

Comment: @CodeLover: If they hadn’t included jQuery, there would be a different error message.

Comment: @lxg I was curious to ask since running the code snippet says `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @CodeLover: Yes, this is due to a faulty usage of the snippet editor. But it has nothing to do with the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running `dataLoader('Prov', sayIamDone());` you are passing to `dataLoader` the **result** of `sayIamDone` function. You have to pass it *without* parenthesis in order to pass the function itself.

```
dataLoader('Prov', sayIamDone);
```

Comment: This little mistake is far more common than you think! Also happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
dataLoader('Prov', sayIamDone());
```

to

```
dataLoader('Prov', sayIamDone);
```

because:

`sayIamDone` is function ,`sayIamDone()` is the result of function.Normally, `sayIamDone()` is `undefined` or return value in the `sayIamDone`;

want to use arguments?you can do this:

```
dataLoader('Prov', callFunc(n));

function callFunc(arg) {
    return function() {
        sayIamDone(arg);
    };
}
```

or more arguments?you can do this by [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
dataLoader('Prov', callFunc(n));

function callFunc(...arg) {
    return function() {
        sayIamDone.apply(null, arg);
    };
}
```

Comment: Care to explain? ;)

Comment: sayIamDone is function ,sayIamDone() is the result of function.Normally, sayIamDone() is undefined or return value in the sayIamDone

Comment: I know that. But please extend your answer to include an explaination, so that other people know the reason why this works.

Comment: oooo my Hat! 2 days to find something that simple